# Delete Parent Registry Key based on value

Tags: batch-file, registry, profile

I know there are other topics on here with an identical goal, but don't think there's one in batch file format so here goes :

I've done a simple reg query in a batch , to find the registry key containing a user profile.

```
set /p username= please enter the user name ?
reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /f "C:\users\%username%" /d /s /e
```

this finds the exact key I'm looking for which is

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-1908996837-4138030977-3423296585-49875

I then want to delete that key and all that is in it,  but the output of the reg query command is actually giving 3 different results, which is making it difficult for me to use in a for loop.

Here's what it actually outputs to a text file

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-1908996837-4138030977-3423296585-49875
>
> ProfileImagePath    REG_EXPAND_SZ    C:\Users\Mr Smith
>
> End of search: 1 match(es) found.

So the next line I have is a for loop which obviously, based on the output of the above command, is not quite doing what I want

```
for /F %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /f "C:\users\%username%" /d /s /e') do reg delete %%a /f
```

So the ultimate aim being to perform this

```
reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-1908996837-4138030977-3423296585-49875" /va /f
```

but obviously without knowing the and typing in the full key name

Thanks

Comment: Firstly, use a different variable than `%username%`.  That's a reserved variable containing the username of the current logged on user.  Next, this sort of thing makes me nervous.  You're going to be leaving a bunch of orphaned profiles in HKU and directories in C:\Users.  It's best to use the dialog resulting from `rundll32.exe sysdm.cpl,EditUserProfiles` to delete user profiles.

Comment: thanks for the tip rojo,  I only used that variable name for ease of example on here but good point.  So is there any way i could still set a variable as the name of a user account, and then direct that variable to the edituserprofiles dialog? In otherwords, not really having to use the dialog at all and have it done automatically?

Answer (score 0):

The `Net User` command-line tool could help system administrators to add, delete or modify user accounts...

`Net User /?` output is too succinct, so [learn more](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/net-user-command-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bump an old post, but I had the same Q. Here is your A:

```
set /p targetUser=Please enter the user name: 

for /F "tokens=*" %%a in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList" /f "C:\users\%targetUser%" /d /s /e ^| FIND /I "HKEY" ') do set "userRegKey=%%a"

reg delete "%userRegKey%" /va /f
```